# Solving a second order differential question where one solution is known.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Given that $y = e^{2x}$ is a solution of
$$ (2x+1)y'' - 4(x+1)y' + 4y = 0 $$
find a linearly independent solution by reducing the order. Write the general solution.

Answer:

Let $y = e^{2x}v$. We have:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=  e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \\
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx}
 + 4 e^{2x} v \\
%
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v \\
\end{align*}
Now we substitute into the original equation:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1) \left(  e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left( e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \right) + 4 e^{2x}v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4  v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2  v \right) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + (2x+1)(4v) - 4(x+1)(2v) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + 8xv - 8xv + 4v - 8v + 4v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now let $w = \dfrac{dv}{dx}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1)\left( \dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4w \right)  -4(x+1)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + (8x +4 - 4x -4)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4xw &= 0 \\
(2x+1) \, dw + 4xw \, dx &= 0 \\
\dfrac{dw}{w} + \left( \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} \right) \, dx &= 0 
\end{align*}
Note:
$$ \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} = 2 - \dfrac{2}{2x+1} $$
\begin{align*}
\ln{|w|}  + 2x - 2\ln{|2x+1|} &= c_1 \\
\ln{|w|}  + 2x - \ln{(2x+1)^2} &= c_1 \\
\ln{ \dfrac{|w|}{(2x+1)^2}} + 2x &= c_1 \\
e^{2x}\left( \dfrac{w}{(2x+1)^2}\right) &= c_2 \\
\end{align*}
Now we solve for $w$.
\begin{align*}
w &= c_2(2x+1)^2 e^{2x} \\
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &=  c_2(2x+1)^2 e^{2x} \\
dv &=  c_2(2x+1)^2 e^{2x} \, dx
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, I find that:
$$ \int (2x+1)^2 e^{2x} \,\, dx = xe^{2x} + C$$
Now we have:
\begin{align*}
v &=  C_1xe^{2x} + C_2 \\
e^{-2x}y &=  C_1xe^{2x} + C_2 \\
y &=  C_1xe^{4x} + C_2e^{2x} \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1e^{2x} + c_2(x+1) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answe4r which I feel is closer but it is still wrong.

Answer:

Let $y = e^{2x}v$. We have:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=  e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \\
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx}
 + 4 e^{2x} v \\
%
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v
\end{align*}
Now we substitute into the orignal equation:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1) \left(  e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left( e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \right) + 4 e^{2x}v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4  v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2  v \right) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + (2x+1)(4v) - 4(x+1)(2v) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + 8xv - 8xv + 4v - 8v + 4v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now let $w = \dfrac{dv}{dx}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1)\left( \dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4w \right)  -4(x+1)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + (8x +4 - 4x -4)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4xw &= 0 \\
(2x+1) \, dw + 4xw \, dx &= 0 \\
\dfrac{dw}{w} + \left( \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} \right) \, dx &= 0 
\end{align*}
Note:
$$ \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} = 2 - \dfrac{2}{2x+1} $$
\begin{align*}
\ln{|w|}  + 2x - 2\ln{|2x+1|} &= c_1 \\
\ln{|w|} &= -2x +  2\ln{|2x+1|} + c_1 \\
w &= c_2 (2x+1)^2 e^{-2x}
\end{align*}
Now we solve for $v$. \
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= c_2 (2x+1)^2 e^{-2x} \\
v &= c_3e^{-2x}(4x^2+8x+5) + c_4 \\
e^{-2x}y &=  c_3e^{-2x}(4x^2+8x+5) + c_4 \\
y &=  c_3(4x^2+8x+5) + c_4 e^{2x}\\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1e^{2x} + c_2(x+1) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer which I believe is correct:

Answer:

Let $y = e^{2x}v$. We have:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=  e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \\
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx}
 + 4 e^{2x} v \\
%
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v
\end{align*}
Now we substitute into the orignal equation:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1) \left(  e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left( e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \right) + 4 e^{2x}v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4  v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2  v \right) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + (2x+1)(4v) - 4(x+1)(2v) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + 8xv - 8xv + 4v - 8v + 4v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now let $w = \dfrac{dv}{dx}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1)\left( \dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4w \right)  -4(x+1)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + (8x +4 - 4x -4)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4xw &= 0 \\
(2x+1) \, dw + 4xw \, dx &= 0 \\
\dfrac{dw}{w} + \left( \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} \right) \, dx &= 0 
\end{align*}
Note:
$$ \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} = 2 - \dfrac{2}{2x+1} $$
\begin{align*}
\ln{|w|}  + 2x - \ln{|2x+1|} &= c_1 \\
\ln{|w|} &= -2x +  \ln{|2x+1|} + c_1 \\
w &= c_2 (2x+1) e^{-2x}
\end{align*}
Now we solve for $v$.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= c_2 (2x+1) e^{-2x} \\
v &= c_3e^{-2x}(2x+1) + c_4 \\
e^{-2x}y &=  c_3e^{-2x}(2x+1) + c_4 \\
y &=  c_3(2x+1) + c_4 e^{2x}\\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1e^{2x} + c_2(x+1) $$
They match.

I made a mistake using the online integral calculator. Here is my solution which I believe is correct. Is it?

Let $y = e^{2x}v$. We have:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=  e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \\
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx}
 + 4 e^{2x} v \\
%
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} &=
 e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v
\end{align*}
Now we substitute into the orignal equation:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1) \left(  e^{2x} \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4 e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4 e^{2x} v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left( e^{2x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2 e^{2x} v \right) + 4 e^{2x}v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 4  v\right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 2  v \right) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + (2x+1)(4v) - 4(x+1)(2v) + 4 v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) + 8xv - 8xv + 4v - 8v + 4v &= 0 \\
%
(2x+1) \left(  \dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + 4  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) 
 -4(x+1)\left(  \dfrac{dv}{dx} \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now let $w = \dfrac{dv}{dx}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
(2x+1)\left( \dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4w \right)  -4(x+1)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + (8x +4 - 4x -4)w &= 0 \\
(2x+1)\dfrac{dw}{dx} + 4xw &= 0 \\
(2x+1) \, dw + 4xw \, dx &= 0 \\
\dfrac{dw}{w} + \left( \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} \right) \, dx &= 0 
\end{align*}
Note:
$$ \dfrac{4x}{2x+1} = 2 - \dfrac{2}{2x+1} $$
\begin{align*}
\ln{|w|}  + 2x - \ln{|2x+1|} &= c_1 \\
\ln{|w|} &= -2x +  \ln{|2x+1|} + c_1 \\
w &= c_2 (2x+1) e^{-2x}
\end{align*}
Now we solve for $v$. \
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= c_2 (2x+1) e^{-2x} \\
v &= c_3e^{-2x}(x+1) + c_4 \\
e^{-2x}y &=  c_3e^{-2x}(x+1) + c_4 \\
y &=  c_3(x+1) + c_4 e^{2x}\\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1e^{2x} + c_2(x+1) $$
They match.

Comment: Integral that you used online calculator for has other value. Wolfram says it is $\frac{1}{2}\exp\{2x\}(4x^2+1)+C$

Comment: The differential of $xe^{2x}$ is $(2x+1)e^{2x}$, so a power of the polynomial factor is missing in the input...

Comment: I think I made a mistake entering the integral into the online  calculator, I am going to update the post.

Answer (score 0):

As an extended comment.

The reduction order method follows the procedure: given a linear differential operator $\mathcal{D}[\cdot]$ and given $y(x)$ such that $\mathcal{D}[y(x)]=0$ we have

$$
\mathcal{D}_1[v(x) y(x)]-v(x)\mathcal{D}_1[y(x)]=\mathcal{D}_2[v(x)]
$$

note that $\mathcal{D}_1[y(x)]=0$. Now  $\mathcal{D}_2[v(x)]$ represents an ode in $v(x)$ with reduced order regarding $\mathcal{D}_1[y(x)]$. In our case

$$
\mathcal{D}_1[\cdot]=\left((2x+1)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-4(x+1)\frac{d}{dx}+4\right)[\cdot]
$$

and making

$$
\mathcal{D}_1[v(x) y(x)]-v(x)\mathcal{D}_1[y(x)]
$$

we have

$$
(2x+1)(y'' v+2v' y' + y v'')-4(x+1)(y' v+v' y)+4 y v = (2x+1)(2v' y'+y v'')-4(x+1)(v' y)=y(2x+1)v''+(2y'(2x+1)-4y(x+1))v'=0
$$

now making $y = e^{2x}$ we have

$$
(2x+1)v''+4x v'=0
$$